# Projection in $\ell_1$ norm onto linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, projection

In the context of $\mathbb{R}^n$, fix a linear subspace $\mathcal{U}$ or arbitrary dimension $r \leq n$ and some vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

What is the most efficient way to compute the projection of $\mathbf{x}$ onto $\mathcal{U}$ in $\ell_1$, that is, how had one ought to solve the optimization problem:

$\mathbf{u}^* = \min_{\mathbf{u} \in \mathcal{U}} ||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{x}||_1$

I have a hard time believing this is not a well understood problem but I am having difficulty with Google.

One could clearly formulate this as a linear program, but I am primarily concerned with high dimensional problems for $n$ large. Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $\displaystyle\min_{\mathbf{u}\in\mathcal{U}}||\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{x}||_1=\min\{r\in\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0} : \mathcal{U}\cap B_1(\mathbf{x},r)\neq\emptyset\}$, where
$$B_1(\mathbf{x},r)=\{\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n : ||\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}||_1\leqslant r\}$$
is the closed $l_1$-ball with center $\mathbf{x}$ and radius $r$. It is the convex hull of
$$E_1(\mathbf{x},r)=\{\mathbf{x}\pm r\mathbf{e}_k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\},$$
where $(\mathbf{e}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{e}_n)$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It follows that
$$\displaystyle\min_{\mathbf{u}\in\mathcal{U}}||\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{x}||_1=r^\ast\implies\mathcal{U}\cap E_1(\mathbf{x},r^\ast)\neq\emptyset,$$
the minimum is attained at any (not necessarily unique) element $\mathbf{u}^\ast$ of the last set, and the convex hull of all such $\mathbf{u}^\ast$ is the solution to the original problem.

So the whole problem reduces to finding the minimum of at most $n$ real numbers
$$r_k = \inf\{|r| : \mathbf{x}+r\mathbf{e}_k\in\mathcal{U}\},\quad 1\leqslant k\leqslant n$$
(with $\inf\ \emptyset$ considered to be $+\infty$).

Comment: (The same with arbitrary norms - the unit sphere being crucial to consider.)

Comment: I see, so projection in $\ell_1$ generally only involves changing one coordinate of the vector to be projected? Perhaps this explains why it is not often used. Interesting, I imagine it is easy to compute the infimum in your final expression?

Comment: Also, it seems that my use of a double negative made the expression difficult to understand: what I'm effectively saying is: "surely this problem is well understood' in my original post.

Comment: Yes, the infimum is easy to compute (either it is $0$, or there is at most single $r$). For "double negative", I'm sorry for inattentive reading ;)